# MySQL pivot tables - rows to colums

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table, time-and-attendance

This Query

```
SELECT
    Student.StudentID,
    student.`Name`,
    attendance.Date,
    CASE
WHEN attendance.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN
    'Present'
ELSE
    'Absent'
END AS Attendance_Status
FROM
    student
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
```

give me this result

> [image: Figure 1]

How can I get a result similar to this

> [image: Figure 2]

Comment: Are you looking to do this in MySQL or PHP?

Comment: @Sean I am building a web application so I will be doing this in PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by this answer

> SELECT    student.StudentID,  student.`Name`,
>
> IF (  (       SELECT DISTINCT             1       FROM            attendance      WHERE
>             attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID        AND date = '2015-09-07'
>     ) = 1,  'Present',  'Absent' ) AS `2015-09-07`,
>
> IF (  (       SELECT DISTINCT             1       FROM            attendance      WHERE
>             attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID        AND date = '2015-09-14'
>     ) = 1,  'Present',  'Absent' ) AS `2015-09-14`,
>
> student.WorkshopID FROM  student

by @Hitesh Mundra

Comment: I'm sorry but there's no way this is the answer with what you've put in the request above.